# objective c interface access

Tags: iphone, objective-c

this my first interface in a.h file.

```
@interface EventRow : NSObject 
{
NSString *title;
NSString *photo;
NSString *description;

NSMutableArray *photoArray;
}
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *photo;
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *description;

@property (nonatomic , retain) NSMutableArray *photoArray;

@end
```

in the same file second

```
@interface PhotoRow : NSObject
{
//NSString *image;

NSMutableArray *imageArray;
}
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSMutableArray *imageArray;

@end
```

Now every object of "PhotoRow" with filled array(imageArray) stored into the "photoArray" array in EventRow's object.

Now I want to count the total elements of "imageArray" . But getting problem in access it through the EventRow's object.

any suggestions ?

Thanks..

Comment: What is the problem you're getting?

Comment: i guess it should work. can iu plz share the code for count the total element of image array..

Comment: I have create an object of EventRow and want to count the imageArray's element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the individual objects in photoArray (eventRow is an instance of EventRow

```
[[eventRow photoArray] objectAtIndex: someIndex]; // I don't like dot notation!
```

or

```
[eventRow.photoArray objectAtIndex: someIndex];
```

To access the imageArray

```
[[[eventRow photoArray] objectAtIndex: someIndex] imageArray];
```

or

```
[eventRow.photoArray objectAtIndex: someIndex].imageArray;
```

To get the count of images for that imageArray

```
[[[[eventRow photoArray] objectAtIndex: someIndex] imageArray] count];
```

or

```
[eventRow.photoArray objectAtIndex: someIndex].imageArray.count;
```

If you want to count all of the images, you need loops but you can use fast enumeration to simplifiy things

```
size_t total = 0;
for (PhotoRow* photoRow in  [eventRow photoArray])
{
    total += [[photoRow imageArray] count];
}
```

However, I'd like you to rethink your design a bit.  Your exposure of the NSMutableArray in each class breaks encapsulation.  Once a caller has got hold of the array, it can modify the internal state of a PhotoRow or an EventRow without the object knowing about it.  It would be better not to have the NSMutableArray properties but to add methods to add images and photoRows directly to PhotoRows and EventRows respectively.  So, for instance your photoRow class might have the following methods:

```
-(size_t) imageCount; // returns the result of sending -count to the internal array
-(NSImage*) imageAtIndex: (size_t) index; // returns the result of sending -objectAtIndex: to the underlying array
-(void) addImage: (NSImage*) newImage;
// etc
```

Comment: thanks for explanation but index comes from table so many times index goes out of bond ....

Comment: +1: Nice encapsulation reeducation. Would exposing an `NSArray` also allow modification, since it could be casted to an `NSMutableArray`? Obviously if the `NSArray` was not readonly, then it could be explicitly set?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer: When I was writing the bit about encapsulation, I did think about adding a bit about exposing an `NSArray`.  I think that probably would be OK.  Note that exposing an `NSArray` and then just returning the internal NSMutableArray is acceptable provided that you know all callers will abide by the API contract. It's against Apple conventions if they don't. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW63

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, your `photoArray` variable in your `EventRow` class contains `PhotoRow` objects. You can count the objects in the `PhotoRow`s `imageArray` variable like so:

```
int someIndex = 0;
[((PhotoRow*)[myEventRow.photoArray objectAtIndex:someIndex]).imageArray count];
```

Comment: i want to count the total element of imageArray through the EventRow's object like [[eventRow.photoArray imageArray]count]];

Comment: Use `-count` to get the count of objects in an NSArray, not `-length`.

Comment: @Jeremy: Thanks. Waayy too early for coding. Caffeine hasn't kicked in yet.

Comment: @maulik: This should do it. Of course you will need to know the index of the object for which you wish to retrieve the `ImageArray`.

Comment: @FreeAslnBeer: ya i did.. i got index from indexPath.row .. it gives me the EventRow's object. Now i have to fetch the imageArray's object which is stored in photoArray array